# Remove invalid nodes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to remove invalid child nodes from `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags.
Like I have html something like:

```
<ul><table>..</table><h1>dfds</h1><li>sfd</li></ul>
```

Specifically, in this example, I want to remove any tag that resides inside `<ul>` other than `<li>`. I just want `<ul><li>sfd</li></ul>` from the Html string.

I want to do this with server side, I can use HtmlAglityPack for this. I am using c#.

This is not regular unclosed tag issue, this is a different case, parsing of html in PDF is the issue. If you want to try, use iTextsharp xml worker DLL, and try to parse this html to PDF, it will throw exception:

```
<html><body><ul><h1>test</h1><li>dsdsf</li></ul></body></html>
```

The ending of tags can be controlled through HtmlDocument class properties which are as follows:

```
OptionOutputAsXml = true,
OptionCheckSyntax = true,
OptionFixNestedTags = true,
OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true,
OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787449/html-agility-pack-removing-unwanted-tags-without-removing-content

Comment: Because <ul> cannot contain <table> <h1> tags , I need to convert html to pdf , I am using iTextsharp for this, whenever structure for <ul> is like that, it throws exception of unable to convert listitem.text to listitem

Comment: @Rakesh sadhula, its not that I don't wnat specific tags, I want to remove any tag that resdie inside <ul> other than <li>

Comment: Why is it down voted? can down voter give reason for this?

Comment: Because you are asking for code. This isn't a ask for code site. Show us what you have tried already or I will give you another downvote.

Comment: @MaciejLos using regex to parse HTML is very bad practice and should be avoided at all times.

Answer (score 1):

See [working demo example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e3fAb9) below :

```
var raw = @"<ul><table>..</table><h1>dfds</h1><li>sfd</li></ul>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(raw);

//inspect all <ul> and <ol> elements
var elementsToBeChecked = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[self::ul or self::ol]");
foreach (HtmlNode element in elementsToBeChecked)
{
    //iterate through all non <li> child element and remove them
    foreach (HtmlNode invalidElement in element.SelectNodes("*[not(self::li)]"))
    {
        invalidElement.Remove();
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```

**output :**

```
<ul><li>sfd</li></ul>
```

Comment: I tried this code, its throwing object reference exception!

Comment: what is the line that triggered exception?

Answer (score 1):

```
string x = "<ul><table>..</table><h1>dfds</h1><li>sfd</li></ul>";
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(x);
HtmlNodeCollection hNC = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul/*");
foreach (HtmlNode h in hNC)
{
    if(h.Name != "li")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Removes tag: "+h.Name);
        h.Remove();       
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/ul").InnerHtml);
```