# Need data inside the Body tag, but no any other tag

Tags: c#, html, regex, streamreader

Hi I have Resume in the html format, 
I am reading file using StreamReader ,and I am removing tags using below method.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("\\Myfile.html"))
                {
                    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    string jj = Regex.Replace(line, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
    }
```

***Its working Damn Cool***

But however as per my requirement I need the data only inside the body tag.
but no body tag, and with no tags inside.

Comment: Try `<body.*?>` instead of `<.*?>` - Still a bit unclear what you're after.

Comment: Just skip lines until `<body>` is found and then execute the code you have until `</body>` is found

Comment: Try `string jj = Regex.Replace(line.Substring(line.IndexOf("<body>", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)), "<[^>]+>", String.Empty);`

Comment: Check my answer and tell  me if something is not clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew working for me , u r osm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Regex for HTML/XML parsing. Use Html/Xml parser. Here is explain well why you should not use it.

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

[Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg?rq=1)

You can load the string in Html document using HTML Agility pack

Here little example of how to do it:

```
public string ReplacePElement() 
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(htmlFile);

    foreach(HtmlNode p in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("body"))
    {

    }

    return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}
```

Comment: So only text will be the output , no any tag , right ?

Comment: for removing all the tags from body ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787449/html-agility-pack-removing-unwanted-tags-without-removing-content