# HTMLAgilityPack - Remove Node but retain its value

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

ive read in this site that this question is ask before. but i tried the code but its not working

all the answers are the same. using a single code

```
item.ParentNode.RemoveChild(item, true);
```

but i used that in my code but it doesnt work. i received an error

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

this is my code as of now

```
try
            {
                string html = "<xml><span> some text </span><p><span> Hello</span> </p></xml>";
                var htmlSpan = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlSpan.LoadHtml(html);
                var rootSpan = htmlSpan.DocumentNode;
                var anchorsSpan = rootSpan.Descendants("span");
                foreach (var item in anchorsSpan)
                {
                    item.ParentNode.RemoveChild(item, true);
                }
                //htmlSpan.Save(fileName);
                Console.WriteLine(htmlSpan.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

what am i doing is removing the span tag but retain is text

so the output must be

```
<xml> some text <p> Hello </p></xml>
```

Comment: Have a look at [removing unwanted tags without removing content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12836974/3796048)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
            foreach (var item in anchorsSpan.ToArray())
            {
                item.ParentNode.RemoveChild(item, true);
            }
```

The `Descendants` function returns a dynamic list of child elements that is built while traversing over it. So, it is not allowed to change the document while traversing over the dynamic list. The solution is to make a static copy of the list beforehand (using `ToArray`) and traverse over that array.

Comment: Thank you. it works now. but why is it that the output is

<xml> some text <p> Hello </p><xml></xml></xml>

why does is create another xml tag?

Comment: @pdfasker Can't reproduce the problem. I get the expected result without any added text.