# Removing HTML from messages safely

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I need to output all of the plaintext within messages that may include valid and/or invalid HTML and possibly text that is superficially similar to HTML (i.e. non-HTML text within `<...>` such as: `< why would someone do this?? >`).

It is more important that I preserve *all non-HTML content* than it is to strip out all HTML, but ideally I would like to get rid of as much of the HTML as possible for readability.

I am currently using HTML Agility Pack, but I am having issues where non-HTML within `<` and `>` is also removed, for example:

my function:

```
text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(text);
text = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

simple example input*:

```
this text has <b>weird < things</b> going on >
```

actual output (unacceptable, lost the word "things"):

```
this text has weird going on >
```

desired output:

```
this text has weird < things going on >
```

Is there a way to remove only legitimate HTML tags within HTML Agility Pack without stripping out other content that may include `<` and/or `>`? Or do I need to manually create a white-list of tags to remove like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787449/html-agility-pack-removing-unwanted-tags-without-removing-content)? That is my fallback solution but I'm hoping there is a more complete solution built in to HTML Agility Pack (or another tool) that I just haven't been able to find.

*(real input often has a ton of unneeded HTML in it, I can give a longer example if that would be useful)

Comment: When dealing with broken HTML, you're going to have defects.  It isn't surprising at all that HTMLAgilityPack interprets `things` as part of the HTML content.  The library has to guess using heuristics when the HTML isn't valid, and those heuristics aren't perfect.  You won't get much better, even if you write your own parser like in the answer by Kevin.

Comment: I've found the regex `/<[^>]>/` to be a good way to find and remove tags. So `Regex.Replace(input,"<[^>]>","")` should be a good starting place. Still, avoiding the parsing of HTML entirely would be better if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this pattern to replace the HTML tags:

```
</?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 \"=_-]*?>
```

Explanation:

```
<
 maybe / (as it may be closing tag)
     match a-z or A-Z as the first letter
        MAYBE match any of a-z, or A-Z, 0-9, "=_- indefinitely
          >
```

Final Code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace Regular
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string yourText = "this text has <b>weird < things</b> going on >";
            string newText = Regex.Replace(yourText, "</?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 \"=_-]*>", "");
            Console.WriteLine(newText);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> this text has weird < things going on >

---

[@corey-ogburn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160527/corey-ogburn)'s comment is not correct as <[space]abc> would be replaced.

---

As you only want to strip them off the string I don't see a reason where you'd want to check if you have a tag starting/ending, but you could easily make it with regex.

---

It's not always a good choice to use RegEx to parse HTML, but I think it'd be fine if you want to parse simple text.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a really long time ago to do something similar. You might use it as a starting point:

You'll need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

And the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Instances of this class strip HTML/XML tags from a string
/// </summary>
public class HTMLStripper
{
    public HTMLStripper() { }
    public HTMLStripper(string source)
    {
        m_source = source;
        stripTags();
    }

    private const char m_beginToken = '<';
    private const char m_endToken = '>';
    private const char m_whiteSpace = ' ';

    private enum tokenType
    {
        nonToken = 0,
        beginToken = 1,
        endToken = 2,
        escapeToken = 3,
        whiteSpace = 4
    }

    private string m_source = string.Empty;
    private string m_stripped = string.Empty;
    private string m_tagName = string.Empty;
    private string m_tag = string.Empty;
    private Int32 m_startpos = -1;
    private Int32 m_endpos = -1;
    private Int32 m_currentpos = -1;
    private IList<string> m_skipTags = new List<string>();
    private bool m_tagFound = false;
    private bool m_tagsStripped = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the source string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The source string.
    /// </value>
    public string source { get { return m_source; } set { clear(); m_source = value; stripTags(); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the string stripped of HTML tags.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The string.
    /// </value>
    public string stripped { get { return m_stripped; } set { } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether [HTML tags were stripped].
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> if [HTML tags were stripped]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool tagsStripped { get { return m_tagsStripped; } set { } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the name of an HTML tag to skip stripping (leave in the text).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public void addSkipTag(string value)
    {
        if (value.Length > 0)
        {
            // Trim start and end tokens from skipTags if present and add to list
            CharEnumerator tmpScanner = value.GetEnumerator();
            string tmpString = string.Empty;
            while (tmpScanner.MoveNext())
            {
                if (tmpScanner.Current != m_beginToken && tmpScanner.Current != m_endToken) { tmpString += tmpScanner.Current; }
            }
            if (tmpString.Length > 0) { m_skipTags.Add(tmpString); }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public void clear()
    {
        m_source = string.Empty;
        m_tag = string.Empty;
        m_startpos = -1;
        m_endpos = -1;
        m_currentpos = -1;
        m_tagsStripped = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears all.
    /// </summary>
    public void clearAll()
    {
        this.clear();
        m_skipTags.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Strips the HTML tags.
    /// </summary>
    private void stripTags()
    {
        // Preserve source and make a copy for stripping
        m_stripped = m_source;
        // Find first tag
        getNext();
        // If there are any tags (if next tag is string.Empty we are at EOS)...
        if (m_tagName != string.Empty)
        {
            do
            {
                // If the tag we found is not to be skipped...
                if (!m_skipTags.Contains(m_tagName))
                {
                    // Remove tag from string
                    m_stripped = m_stripped.Remove(m_startpos, m_endpos - m_startpos + 1);
                    m_tagsStripped = true;
                }
                // Get next tag, rinse and repeat (if next tag is string.Empty we are at EOS)
                getNext();
            } while (m_tagName != string.Empty);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Steps the pointer to the next HTML tag.
    /// </summary>
    private void getNext()
    {
        m_tagFound = false;
        m_tag = string.Empty;
        m_tagName = string.Empty;
        bool beginTokenFound = false;
        CharEnumerator scanner = m_stripped.GetEnumerator();
        // If we're not at the beginning of the string, move the enumerator to the appropriate location in the string
        if (m_currentpos != -1)
        {
            Int32 index = 0;
            do
            {
                scanner.MoveNext();
                index += 1;
            } while (index < m_currentpos + 1);
        }
        while (!m_tagFound && m_currentpos + 1 < m_stripped.Length)
        {
            // Find next begin token
            while (scanner.MoveNext())
            {
                m_currentpos += 1;
                if (evaluateChar(scanner.Current) == tokenType.beginToken)
                {
                    m_startpos = m_currentpos;
                    beginTokenFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If a begin token is found, find next end token
            if (beginTokenFound)
            {
                while (scanner.MoveNext())
                {
                    m_currentpos += 1;
                    // If we find another begin token before finding an end token we are not in a tag
                    if (evaluateChar(scanner.Current) == tokenType.beginToken)
                    {
                        m_tagFound = false;
                        beginTokenFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    // If the char immediately following a begin token is a white space we are not in a tag
                    if (m_currentpos - m_startpos == 1 && evaluateChar(scanner.Current) == tokenType.whiteSpace)
                    {
                        m_tagFound = false;
                        beginTokenFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    // End token found
                    if (evaluateChar(scanner.Current) == tokenType.endToken)
                    {
                        m_endpos = m_currentpos;
                        m_tagFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (m_tagFound)
            {
                // Found a tag, get the info for this tag
                m_tag = m_stripped.Substring(m_startpos, (m_endpos + 1) - m_startpos);
                m_tagName = m_stripped.Substring(m_startpos + 1, m_endpos - m_startpos - 1);
                // If this tag is to be skipped, we do not want to reset the position within the string
                // Also, if we are at the end of the string (EOS) we do not want to reset the position
                if (!m_skipTags.Contains(m_tagName) && m_currentpos != stripped.Length)
                {
                    m_currentpos = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Evaluates the next character.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <returns>tokenType</returns>
    private tokenType evaluateChar(char value)
    {
        tokenType returnValue = new tokenType();
        switch (value)
        {
            case m_beginToken:
                returnValue = tokenType.beginToken;
                break;
            case m_endToken:
                returnValue = tokenType.endToken;
                break;
            case m_whiteSpace:
                returnValue = tokenType.whiteSpace;
                break;
            default:
                returnValue = tokenType.nonToken;
                break;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```