# How to handle <see /> XML documentation tags in Swagger?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have an ASP.Net Web API with XML documentation throughout, including many `<see />` tags.

I've recently added Swagger (Swashbuckle UI stuff) to the solution, and noticed that it doesn't handle XML tags like `<see />`. After looking around online I found this - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/57, so it seems like the devs don't want to fix this.

Does anybody have any suggestions? I tried running a little .exe to replace all tags in the generated XML file with their object names (e.g. `<see cref="MyObject"/>` becomes `MyObject`), but this kept screwing up and even when I did it manually Swagger for some reason didn't pick up the changes (is the XML loaded into memory somewhere?)

Comment: Can you share your configs for `Swashbuckle` and a sample of your XML doc string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from Kit's suggestion, I found a way to retrieve and change the documentation, but needed a way to parse XML tags. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836974/5449886) which, although it refers to HTML, removes XML tags just as well.

So, in the order they are required:

1. I have a common Utilities class where I put the above HtmlAgilityPack code (though I called the method RemoveXMLTags)
2. Added a new XmlDocumentFilter class as below:

```
public class XmlDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
        {
            foreach (var operation in path.Value.Operations)
            {
                operation.Value.Description = Utilities.RemoveXMLTags(operation.Value.Description);

                operation.Value.Summary = Utilities.RemoveXMLTags(operation.Value.Summary);

                if (operation.Value.RequestBody != null)
                {
                    operation.Value.RequestBody.Description = Utilities.RemoveXMLTags(operation.Value.RequestBody.Description);
                }

                foreach (var parameter in operation.Value.Parameters)
                {
                    parameter.Description = Utilities.RemoveXMLTags(parameter.Description);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Added the following to my Startup class:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(setupAction =>
    {
        setupAction.SwaggerDoc(
            "MyAppAPIDocumentation",
            new OpenApiInfo() { Title = "MyApp API", Version = "1" });

        var xmlDocumentationFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlDocumentationFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlDocumentationFile);

        setupAction.IncludeXmlComments(xmlDocumentationFullPath);
        setupAction.DocumentFilter<XmlDocumentFilter>();
    });
```

4. Profit

Answer (score 1):

XML documentation comments are generated [into a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/output#documentationfile) with the same name as the assembly in the same folder (usually). You could parse that file with the [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=net-7.0) and related classes, and then use a [schema filter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#extend-generator-with-operation-schema--document-filters) (`ISchemaFilter`) to set the appropriate properties on the [Open API schema](https://swagger.io/specification/) that Swashbuckle exposes.

I'm unsure of what schema element would be appropriate for a "see also" or "related resources" functionality. You would need to investigate that (perhaps a custom property in [ASP.NET Core's Open API implementation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi), or by appending text to a description property).

As to

> is the XML loaded into memory somewhere?

Yes. Swashbuckle itself parses this XML to do all that it currently does. Roughly speaking it builds it into a document object model (DOM) built on top of Microsoft's Open API implementation mentioned above. Using a schema filter will give you access to that DOM.

Comment: This put me on the right track, still messing around and the code is crap at the moment but when I've tidied it up I'll post, thanks for your help!